# Change the file extension for files in a folder?

Tags: python, file

I would like to change the extension of the files in specific folder. i read about this topic in the forum. using does ideas, I have written following code and I expect that it would work but it does not. I would be thankful for any guidance to find my mistake.

```
   import os,sys
   folder = 'E:/.../1936342-G/test'
   for filename in os.listdir(folder):
           infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
           if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
           oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
           infile= open(infilename, 'r')
           newname = infilename.replace('.grf', '.las')
           output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
           outfile = open(output,'w')
```

Comment: In what manner does it not work? Do the files just not get renamed? Is the any error messages?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, it stops in the line ' output = os.rename(infilename, newname)'

Comment: It just stops? Without any output?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `open` on the source file is unnecessary, since `os.rename` only needs the source and destination paths to get the job done. Moreover, `os.rename` always returns `None`, so it doesn't make sense to call `open` on its return value.

```
import os
import sys
folder = 'E:/.../1936342-G/test'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
    if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
    oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
    newname = infilename.replace('.grf', '.las')
    output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

I simply removed the two `open`. Check if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, as you recommended I changed the position of the line ,it proceed but again would sotck on the line 'outfile = open(output,'w')'

Comment: @user2355306 `os.rename` doesn't seem to return the file path.

Comment: replace is not correct, for example file can have name Smth.grform.grf, @elyase answer is better

Comment: What is the usage of this line `oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)` ?

Comment: @chenaren @jTiKey thank you very much for the codes. however, my files have no any extensions for example, and i would like to put an extension to each file in a folder. in this case, i will be very happy if you have any suggestions... i am not sure this will be still available for my case: `newname = infilename.replace('.grf', '.las')`

Comment: @vdu16 just do `newname = infilename + '.jpg' ` where .jpg is your extension

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to open the files to rename them, `os.rename` only needs their paths. Also consider using the [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob, os

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, '*.grf')):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.las')
```

Comment: it's wrong.
it adds two dots instead of one in the extestion of the file

last line must be changed into:

    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.las')

Comment: @DaniPaniz, sorry what is the difference between your suggestion and what i wrote in my answer?

Comment: I guess it was "-3" in an older version, someone changed it to the correct one

Comment: Great.@elyase how to extend this to subdirectories which also has files to be renamed ?

Answer (score 12):

Something like this will rename all files in the executing directory that end in .txt to .text

```
import os, sys

for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
  base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
  if ext == ".txt":
    os.rename(filename, base_file + ".text")
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. using this code, the running process wouls stock on the last line with the error' system can not find the data' what would be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

import os

```
dir =("C:\\Users\\jmathpal\\Desktop\\Jupyter\\Arista")
for i in os.listdir(dir):
    files = os.path.join(dir,i)
    split= os.path.splitext(files)
    if split[1]=='.txt':
       os.rename(files,split[0]+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please explain what the code you're providing does and what it adds in comparison with the previously existing answers. Also, please avoid using [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) as a variable name. I would also suggest considering unpacking as follows: `root, ext = os.path.splitext(files)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have python 3.4 or later, you can use `pathlib`. It is as follows. This example is for changing `.txt` to `.md`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('./dir')

for f in path.iterdir():
    if f.is_file() and f.suffix in ['.txt']:
        f.rename(f.with_suffix('.md'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding my few cents to improve @Keiku's answer: **use Pathlib with its glob-backed search magic** to simplify the code and enable fancy file matching.

For example, to rename all *.jpg into more proper *.jpeg (some APIs are strict about this distinction) in third-level directories, do:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("/home").glob("kaggle-data/*/*/*jpg"):
    path.rename(path.with_suffix('.jpeg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Batch renames file's extension in a given directory
'''

import os
import sys
from os.path import join
from os.path import splitext

def main():
    try:
        work_dir, old_ext, new_ext = sys.argv[1:]
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit("Usage: {} directory old-ext new-ext".format(__file__))

    for filename in os.listdir(work_dir):
        if old_ext == splitext(filename)[1]:
            newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
            os.rename(join(work_dir, filename), join(work_dir, newfile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

With print and validation.

```py
import os
from os import walk

mypath = r"C:\Users\you\Desktop\test"
suffix = ".png"
replace_suffix = ".jpg"
filenames = next(walk(mypath), (None, None, []))[2]
for filename in filenames:
    if suffix in filename:
        print(filename)
rep =  input('Press y to valid rename : ')
if rep == "y":
    for filename in filenames:
        if suffix in filename:
            os.rename(mypath+"\\"+filename, mypath+"\\"+filename.replace(suffix, replace_suffix))
```