# Writing from .txt to .md in python

Tags: python, markdown

How can I read a `.txt` file in python and write those contents into a `.md` file without any change in content. I have googled enough but couldn't find a proper answer . ?

Comment: [shutil.copyfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile)

Comment: Just to make it clear, you literally mean "the exact same bytes as a `.md` file instead of a `.txt` file", right? If so, then it's a dup. Probably of [How do I copy a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python), which has a variety of great answers with all the info you could ever want.

Comment: … except that you might also want to know about `os.path.splitext` to help you convert `"spam.txt"` to `"spam.md"` if that `"spam.txt"` is a value in a variable rather than a constant in your source.

Comment: Thanks ! I have enough resource now .

Comment: I was still wondering, if writing to a `.md` file directly is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not changing the contents you could just change the file extension. See this SO answer for help

[Change the file extension for files in a folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736080/change-the-file-extension-for-files-in-a-folder-in-python)

**Edited based on comment**
If you want to make a copy this is the simplest way I believe

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile("testcopy.txt", "testcopy.md")
```

Comment: I want to write the contents to another file . Is there a way in python to make a copy of this file and then change its extension !?

Comment: @saru95: Sure. See the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module.